# Creating an Interactice timeline in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am creating an interactive Timeline in Vue.js and have a base code set up. What currently happens is when you select a year, content shows up but to make it disappear you need to click it again.

What I am trying to do is make the content of the previous year disappear when you click another year.
The Codepen I created is linked below:

[Vue JS Timeline](https://codepen.io/JoshHodson/pen/wYMrZo)

As you can see, my Vue JS code has different set ups for showing the data.

```
var vue = new Vue({
el:"#app",
data: {
    nowShowing: false,
    nowShowing2: false,
    nowShowing3: false,
    nowShowing4: false,
    isShowing:false,

    message: 'test1',
    message2: 'test2',
    message3: 'test3',
    message4: 'test4',
    message5: 'test5',
}});
```

Then going into the HTML you have a button class

```
<button class="c-History__year" @click="isShowing ^= true">1880</button>
```

And the div class:

```
<div v-show="isShowing">
    <p class="c-History__summary">
        {{message}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Is this possible to complete in Vue with transitioning or would CSS suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've bundled all the `isShowing` variables into just one and the divs are now looking for whether the `isShowing` var has a specific number and when does, the div will be shown and all others will be hidden.

JS:

```
 const vue = new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data: {
            showing: -1,

            message: 'test1',
            message2: 'test2',
            message3: 'test3',
            message4: 'test4',
            message5: 'test5',
        },})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="o-Container o-Container--padded">
        <div class="c-History">
            <div class="c-History__timeline">
                <div class="c-History__years">
                    <span class="c-History__line"></span>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showing = 0">1880</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showing = 1">1938</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showing = 2">1971</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showing = 3">1982</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showing = 4">2007</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <transition name="bounce">
            <div v-show="showing == 0">
                <p class="c-History__summary">
                    {{message}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="bounce">
            <div v-show="showing == 1">
                <p class="c-History__summary">
                    {{message2}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="bounce">
            <div v-show="showing == 2">
                <p class="c-History__summary">
                    {{message3}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="bounce">
            <div v-show="showing == 3">
                <p class="c-History__summary">
                    {{message4}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </transition>
        <transition name="bounce">
            <div v-show="showing == 4">
                <p class="c-History__summary">
                    {{message5}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation and solution thank you. Have the upvote :) An upvote on my question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a different a simpler approach, first you can change your `data` structure like this:

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data: {
        message: 'test1',
        message2: 'test2',
        message3: 'test3',
        message4: 'test4',
        message5: 'test5',
        contentToShow: ''
    },
  methods: {
    showContent(messageIndex) {
      this.contentToShow = this[messageIndex]
    }
  }
})
```

the idea is to have a method where you are going to pass the `index` of message property, and set only one visible `contentToShow`

So your component updated will be

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="o-Container o-Container--padded">
        <div class="c-History">
            <div class="c-History__timeline">
                <div class="c-History__years">
                    <span class="c-History__line"></span>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showContent('message')">1880</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showContent('message2')">1938</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showContent('message3')">1971</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showContent('message4')">1982</button>
                    <button class="c-History__year" @click="showContent('message5')">2007</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <transition name="bounce">
            <div v-show="contentToShow">
                <p :key="contentToShow" class="c-History__summary">
                    {{contentToShow}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this solution also worked however the first solution works better for future work :)